# On delete in Microsoft access 2010( SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem with microsoft access 2010 in SQL. It gives me an syntax error and it highlights "DELETE" when I try to run this SQL statement.

```
CREATE TABLE nextOfKindonorAuth(
    name CHAR(30),
    licenseNo INTEGER,
    phone INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(name, licenseNo),
    FOREIGN KEY(licenseNo)
    REFERENCES Driver
    ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the syntax error, exactly?

Comment: Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your exact error, it looks like you are missing the reference to which column from the Driver table.

```
CREATE TABLE nextOfKindonorAuth(
  name CHAR(30),
  licenseNo INTEGER,
  phone INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY(name, licenseNo),
  FOREIGN KEY(licenseNo)
  REFERENCES Driver(COLUMN)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: Hello I have added the column but it still gives me the same error. Syntax error in CONSTRAINT Clause

Comment: CREATE TABLE nextOfKindonorAuth(
name CHAR(30), 
licenseNo INTEGER, 
phone INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(name, licenseNo),
FOREIGN KEY(licenseNo) REFERENCES Driver(licenseNo) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

Comment: One thing to check would be that the licenseNo column in the Driver table has the same data type as in this table you are trying to create.